# flutter - center overflowing text and clip

Tags: flutter, widget, overflow, clip

to implement a layout-design I'm trying to center and overflow (clip) a text outside the screen (see picture). The clip within the red rectangles is out of the screen and should be clipped.

[image: desired behavious]

I've been able to let the Text overflow the screen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 30),
                child: Text(
                  "DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  softWrap: false,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,),

          );
}
```

but I've not been able to center the text:

[image: The Text is clipped at the end, but not centered]

Does someone have an idea of how to realize this?

Thanks

**Update:**

Thanks to @pungjunghyeon answer the text is now overflowing on the left and on the right. Now I would like to clip the UnconstrainedBox to prevent the overflow warning, but I'm not able to avoid them. Any further hint on this point?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ClipRect(
        child: UnconstrainedBox(

          child: Text(

                "DASHBOARD",
                overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 60,
                  letterSpacing: 20,
                  color: Colors.orange
                ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the **UnconstrainedBox** widget.

**For example :**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    body: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: UnconstrainedBox(
        child: Text(
          'DASHBOARD',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0),
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center
        ),
      )
    ), //Container
  ); // Scaffold
}
```

Comment: This allows the overflow as requested, but the overflow warning is displayed. I tried to wrap the unconstrained box into a ClipRect (see original post modified), but that didn't change anything. Some more hint on this?

Comment: In debug mode, if the child overflows the container, a warning will be printed on the console, and black and yellow striped areas will appear where the overflow occurs.

In release mode, that warning will not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Use **OverflowBox** widget, Compared to **UnconstrainedBox**, this does not generate a warning.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: OverflowBox(
        maxWidth: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          'DASHBOARD',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0),
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ); // Scaffold
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 30),
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit:BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Text(
                    "DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas DASHBOARDasdasdasdasdasdasdas",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    softWrap: false,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
      );
```

Comment: Although this solution provides an interesting behavior, it does not meet the requirements. This solution downsizes the content instead of allowing an overflow.

Comment: If you want overflow, replace FittedBox with Flexible and add textAlign property to center in the Text widget